# Assignment of an object of class NULL is not valid for @sdf in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apache-spark, databricks, sparkr

I am getting below error while running this code in databricks,

I am new to R and spark. Could someone please help me out?

```
%r
sql("REFRESH TABLE view_for_R")
p <- sql("SELECT * FROM view_for_R")
p <- as.data.frame(p)
```

> Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  :
> assignment of an object of class “NULL” is not valid for @‘sdf’ in an object of class “SparkDataFrame”; is(value, "jobj") is not TRUE
> Some( Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass) : assignment of an object of class “NULL” is not valid for @‘sdf’ in an object of class “SparkDataFrame”; is(value, "jobj") is not TRUE )
> Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass) : assignment of an object of class “NULL” is not valid for @‘sdf’ in an object of class “SparkDataFrame”; is(value, "jobj") is not TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the cluster helped resolve the same issue for me.